# I just got an email from Google saying that someone logged in to my account using some different email address?

Tags: gmail

This got me pretty alarmed:

[image]

I immediately checked the devices from which it was accessed but couldn't see any different from what I use usually. Nevertheless, even though I use two-factor authentication, I changed my password immediately.

Now, has any one of you had a similar experience? I thought the "problem" could be related with Google ignoring the dot (.) in the email thus for example john.doe@gmail.com and johndoe@gmail.com would come to the same email address. But, someone used the added numbers 33, so this hardly would pass as the same use case.

Anyways, still kind of baffled about it, so would appreciate some insight from more knowledgeable users.

Comment: you may wish to blur out the address - I now know what your email is.

Comment: That's not my email address. Similar, true - but not my exact one. That's what's puzzling also...

Comment: Yours is `nikola.brenzjak@gmail.com`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you've got here. (I don't speak or read the language. (Slovenian? Croatian?)) I suspect one of two possibilities:

1. Someone logged in (or tried to log in) from an area where you usually aren't. (I might get a message if someone tried to log in from China, when I'm on the East Coast of the U.S.)
2. More likely, I think, is someone has set your email address to be their recovery email or alternate email, and probably by mistake

I think you've done the responsible thing. You're already using two-step authentication and you've changed your password. This probably won't ever come up again. I wouldn't worry any more about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for not translating Croatian (very close guess btw!), but essentially what it says is that someone just signed in to my account nikolabreznjak33@gmail.com, then some details and then the question with a link if I don't recognize this activity. Since this email isn't mine I'm inclined to thinking that the possibility 2 really is the case, be it intentional or unintentional. But yeah, I probably should have a peace of mind having changed the pass immediately and  since I have a two-way auth enabled. Thanks for reassurance!

Answer (score 2):

If the address is not yours it seems to me it's most likely a phishing attempt. Do not click any links in the email. If you want to check things do so through known good means (eg., typing addresses yourself).

Comment: Damn, haven't thought of a well played out phishing attempt. +1